# Issue with Nestedscrollview nested recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nested, keyboard, nestedscrollview

I have a problem

I put a recyclerview in nestedscrollview
when keyboard open, nestedscrollview auto scroll down and edittext loses focus, keyboard hide edittext of item in recyclerview

How to I sloved it

Please, help me !!! Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when using recyclerview & nestedscrollview together.

There are 2 approaches.

1. Disable the nested scrolling of recyclerview by `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`
2. add `softInputMode="adjustPan"` in your activity tag in the Manifest. If `adjustPan` doesn't work, then try `adjustResize`.

And yes. Change your view hierarchy like this :

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
....
<LinearLayout>
...
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
....
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
<LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```